# Nginx - Cannot access website at all

Tags: nginx

We have a -pretty old- website that's in production, working, and I need to copy it on another server (let's call it DEV) to test things out. After configuring Nginx though, I just cannot access it through my browser.

**Server configuration stuff :**
Nginx 1.2.1 , php5.6.8-1 , using Laravel 4.2 framework (yes, pretty old stuff)

**What I did :**
Copy the website on the other server DEV, copy the configuration in the `sites-available` folder to the DEV one, made the symlink with an absolute path in `sites-enabled`, modified the URL in the configuration a bit so it's not the same, copied the needed SSL certificates as well.
Restarted both php5-fpm and nginx (`nginx -t` says everything is okay), and the configuration file is *exactly* the same - minus the URL - as another one on the DEV server, which points to a perfectly working website.

**What happens :**
Firefox (or any browser, mind you) says the server does not exist. There's not even an Nginx error or anything.
Nothing in the logs either - either in `/var/log/nginx` or in the log paths in the configuration below - no access was recorded.

Here's the config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name dummy.name.website;
        rewrite ^ https://dummy.name.website permanent;
}

server {
        listen 443;

        server_name     dummy.name.website;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/cert.key;

        access_log      /srv/http/website/app/storage/logs/access.log;
        error_log       /srv/http/website/app/storage/logs/nginx.log;
        rewrite_log     on;

        root            /srv/http/website/public;
        index           index.php;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        if (!-d $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
        }

        location ~* \.php$ {
                include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index                   index.php;
                fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

I'm just running out of ideas. I got 3 other colleagues on it, nobody has a clue... Thanks for any help :)

Comment: you might want to add the contents of your logfiles to your question! `/srv/http/website/app/storage/logs/access.log`, `srv/http/website/app/storage/logs/nginx.log`

Comment: As pointed out, "Nothing in the logs either, no access was recorded". :(

Comment: If the browser says that *the server does not exist*, then it is a DNS issue rather than a server issue, I would think.

Comment: What machine(s) is the browser(s) running on and what name resolution(s) does it (do they) use, and if DNS what DNS server(s) and do that(those) DNS server(s) have the desired name? Show result of `ping dummy.name.website` (not `nslookup` which does not consistently use same resolution as apps). What _exactly_ is the browser error(s)? What OS is the server on and does it have any firewall or is there any firewall in the network? Is the browser(s) or the browser system(s) configured to use any kind of proxy or special networking like a VPN or Tor?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 `ping <website>` answers "unknown host <website>" - would it be a DNS issue then? The server is on Debian 4.7.2-5 - no proxy, no specific firewalls either. Almost nothing special security-wise has been done on this computer. The error page on Firefox is in french, but you get the same error if you type stuff like www.somethingstupid124890214random.com  ([screenshot](http://atechjourney.com/wp-content/uploads/server-not-found-firefox-browser.jpg) )

Comment: Are you running the DEV server on a local machine? Or, if not, is the server_name's domain registered to the DEV server?

Comment: The website is on a dedicated server, I do think it's the issue now. Setting the URL in the configuration to the server's DNS name and browsing to it works. We (the team) have no idea how to configure the server to make the correct URL work though, since it's been configured more than 2 years ago, and I keep finding really bad examples that don't quite fit the issue online. Any leads on where to look?